# Why can't I sign into Unity Hub?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had some problems with Unity Hub sign in so I uninstalled it and then I installed it again but now I can't even open it because of the sign in problem. [Sign in error screenshot] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld8AK.png)

I'm from Iran so I'm using VPN, but I'm sure the problem is not because of the VPN.
I really need help because my project has interrupted. Please help me .

Comment: Try to set `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` env variables to your proxy address.

Comment: This is not programming related and would be better suited to unity’s own forums.